# Can't get property from request on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, request

when controller try to get request like following, it will work.

```
$test = $request->base;
return response()->json(['test' => $test]);
```

front end will get json like this:

```
{name: "aaaa", price: null, discounted: null, area: null, address: null, …}
```

but when I try to get "name" property:

```
$test = $request->base
$test2 = $test->name;
return response()->json(['test' => $test2]);
```

then I get error at network preview:

```
{message: "Trying to get property of non-object", exception: "ErrorException",…}
```

the reason is because $request->base doesn't get anything anymore.

```
$test = $request->base
$check = gettype($test);  // shows null
$test2 = $test->name;
return response()->json(['test' => $test2]);
```

**why is this happen? how to get property like this:

$request->base->name**

Comment: What's the value of `$request->base`? Are you sure it's an object? Does `$test['name']` work?

Comment: $request->base is a json like following:
 {name: "aaaa", price: null, discounted: null, area: null, address: null, …}

 And it work's when I change $test2=$test->name to  $test2=$test['name'];
 But what is different between  $test2=$test->name and $test2=$test['name']?   Why $test2=$test->name can't work?

Comment: If `$test['name']` works, `$test` is an array, not an object. You access parameters differently in the two data types.

Comment: Seems like I get confused with data types. Thanks for help bro!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this array and objects are different types. In first line we have an array in $test so you won't be able to access inside that using -> operator;

```
$test = $request->base
$test2 = $test['name'];
```

Comment: Thanks, I realized that request's propertys are not  json. This is work.